# Unable to update Android Studio Arctic Fox mac book pro m1

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide, android-studio-arctic-fox, android-ide

[image: this is the screen shot of error msg]

> some conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be
> applied.
>
> contents/jre/contents/home/frameworks/javaNativeFoundation.framework/Version/A/._JavaNativFoundation.tbd

Comment: For every update i will uninstall android studio ? this is not a solution

Comment: I suppose no luck so far? Has there already been an issue filed at Googles issue tracker?

Comment: Already reported at Googles issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198782629